# Tkinter text widget line numbers dissapear after adding new tab in Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create tabs with `Text` widgets inside them. Each of those `Text` widgets have line numbers. When there is only one tab, the line numbers work fine, but when there are multiple tabs, the line numbers don't work on the first tab, and on all the other tabs, there simply aren't any numbers. Below is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        while True:
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]
            self.create_text(5,y,anchor="nw", text=linenum, font=("Courier", 9))
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)

class CustomText(tk.Text): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # generate the event for certain types of commands
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 2] == {mark set insert}) || 
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview scroll}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview scroll})} {

                    event generate  $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }

                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy {widget} _{widget}
        '''.format(widget=str(self)))

        self.comment = False

class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fileName = "Untitled Document"
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.menubar()
        self.createtext()

    def createtext(self):
        self.notebook.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.text = CustomText(self.tab1, bd=0, font=("Courier", 9))  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.tab1, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.text.yview)

        self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self.tab1, width=55)
        self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)

        self.vsb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.notebook.add(self.tab1, text=self.fileName)

        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)

    def addtab(self):
        self.newTab = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.text = CustomText(self.newTab, bd=0, font=("Courier", 9))  

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.newTab, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.configure(command=self.text.yview)

        self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self.newTab, width=55)
        self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)

        self.vsb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.notebook.add(self.newTab, text=self.fileName)

    def menubar(self):
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu)

        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, font=("Courier", 9))
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="New Window", command=self.addtab)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Window", menu=self.fileMenu)

    def _on_change(self, event):
        self.linenumbers.redraw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Window")
    root.geometry("1024x600")
    window = Window(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: At least part of the problem is that you're using `self.linenumbers`, `self.vsb` and `self.text` with more than one widget each.

Comment: @BryanOakley No, that's not the problem. I binded my fucntions and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to `bind` `functions` in the `addtab` `function`.

```
self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)
```

Comment: I'm confused; this sounds like this was the answer